# async XMLHttpRequest blocking UI in Browser

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, browser, xmlhttprequest

I have the following function in the client-side of a web app:

```
function fetchDataFromApi(fetchCode, options, callback) {

    var dataObject = JSON;
    dataObject.fetchCode = fetchCode;
    dataObject.options = options;

    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    var url = "DATA_API_URL"; 

    // connect to the API
    xhr.open("POST", url, true);
    xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type",
        "application/json"
    ); 

    // set callback for when API responds. This will be called once the request is answered by the API.
    xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (xhr.readyState === 4 && xhr.status === 200) {
            // API has responded; 
            var json = {
                ok: false,
                message: 'could not parse response'
            };
            try {
                // parse the raw response into the API response object
                json = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
            } catch (err) {
                // probably json parse error; show raw response and error message
                console.log(err);
                console.log("raw response: " + xhr.responseText);
            } 

            if (json.ok) {
                // success, execute callback with argument json.data
                callback(json.data);
            } else {
                // fetch failed; 
                console.error(json.message);
            }
        }
    }; 

    // send request payload to API
    var data = JSON.stringify(dataObject);
    xhr.send(data);
}
```

Since I am using an asynchronous call (the third parameter in `xhr.open` is set to `true`), I am surprised to find that this function blocks the UI in the browser. When there is a substantial amount of data grabbed from the server with this function, it can take 3-4 seconds, blocking the UI and generating this error in the Chrome console:

```
[Violation] 'load' handler took 3340ms
```

This function is [currently in production here](https://forms.thedivinemercy.org/chj/confraternity.php), where I am calling the function as so:

```
function getNamesFromApi() {
    fetchDataFromApi('chj-confraternity-list', {}, function (data) {
        fadeReplace(document.getElementById('spinner-2'), document.getElementById(
                'name-list-container'),
            false, true);
        // transaction was successful; display names
        var listString = "";
        if (data.list) {
            // add the names to the page
            var listLength = data.list.length;
            for (var x = 0; x < listLength; x++) {
                document.getElementById('name-list-container').innerHTML +=
                    "<div class='name-list-item'>" +
                    "<span class='name-list-name'>" +
                    data.list[x].name +
                    "</span>" +
                    "<span class='name-list-location'>" +
                        data.list[x].location +
                    "</span>" +
                    "</div>";
            }
        }
    });
}

window.addEventListener('load', function() {
    getNamesFromApi();
});
```

Why is this blocking the UI, and what am I doing wrong in making an asynchronous XMLHttpRequest?

UPDATE: Thanks to the comments for pointing me in the right direction; the issue was not the XMLHttpRequest, but rather me appending innerHTMl within a loop. The issue is now fixed, with the corrected snippet in the answer.

Comment: when do you call the function?

Comment: @Itamar I typically call the function as the page loads, and sometimes after some user action (like to update some info)

Comment: Sounds odd. Could it just take that long for the server to respond? How do you know the UI is actually blocked?

Comment: @JacobPenney it does take that long for the server to respond. I can tell the UI is blocked because i can't interact with any elements on the page until the request is finished. Here is the code in production: [link](https://forms.thedivinemercy.org/chj/confraternity.php) While the loading spinner is visible, try entering input in the form.

Comment: Can you add the snippet where you call fetchDataFromApi? The main thread should not be blocked by an unfulfilled XHRHTTP request. There are two possibilities that I can think of: 1) there's a flag variable for whether the data has loaded blocking interaction, or 2) there's a recursive loop attempting to load the data into the UI, calling itself until the data is present. Can you confirm whether there's a flag set after the response or if it's called in a recursive/iterative loop?

Comment: @JacobPenney I have added the snipped which uses the function. I don't believe there is a flag variable which is blocking interaction, at least not one which I have placed on purpose. There is a loop in the callback in the snippet; could that be what is blocking the UI?

Comment: You should run your code  that generates the HTML within a web worker. That's what's blocking the UI not the XHR. Also,  don't append to innerHTML in a loop, that is a really expensive operation. Your web worker should return a string that you assign only once to innerHTML

Comment: @JuanMendes You were correct, the blocking was coming from appending to innerHTML inside the loop. Instead, I now append to a string and then set innerHTML to that string after the loop has completed. This is also much faster. Thanks

Comment: There's no need for an update, your own answer is already an indication of the update. It's fine to answer your own question, even if you used a hint from the comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The UI was blocked because i was appending innerHTML within a loop, an expensive, and UI-blocking operation. The issue is now fixed. Here is the corrected snippet:

```
function getNamesFromApi() {
    fetchDataFromApi('chj-confraternity-list', {}, function (data) {
        fadeReplace(document.getElementById('spinner-2'), document.getElementById(
                'name-list-container'),
            false, true);
        // transaction was successful; display names
        if (data.list) {
            var listString = "";
            // add the names to the page
            var listLength = data.list.length;
            for (var x = 0; x < listLength; x++) {
                listString +=
                    "<div class='name-list-item'>" +
                    "<span class='name-list-name'>" +
                    data.list[x].name +
                    "</span>" +
                    "<span class='name-list-location'>" +
                        data.list[x].location +
                    "</span>" +
                    "</div>";
            }
            document.getElementById('name-list-container').innerHTML = listString;
        }
    });
}

window.addEventListener('load', function() {
    getNamesFromApi();
});
```

Comment: @JuanMendes maybe in the future, i'll have to look into those. thanks